# How to IK Rig a human arm with external controllers?

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

[image]

So in the above image:
Symbol   Description

S      - Shoulder

U      - Upper Arm

L      - Lower Arm

W      - Wrist

F      - Fingers

Now, I have to IK-rig it from upper arm to fingers and I was hoping for someone to explain how to go about this as I couldn't find a simple enough video to understand; I am relatively new rigging. You can just rig one of the fingers and adapt it to the rest and just explain what the differences are between rigging a finger and rigging a thumb.
If you could do so by posting screenshots, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Josh said there are many ways to rig an arm, here is one basic:

- Add a *Target* bone and a *Poletarget* bone to your arm. The *Target* will be the arm controller, the *Poletarget* will determine the arm orientation.
- Parent these 2 bones to the *Root* bone of your armature.
- If don't have a *Root* bone yet, at least deparent these 2 bones.
- Disable their *Deform* option in *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Deform*: When you'll parent the armature these 2 bones won't deform the mesh.
- Parent the *Hand* bone to the *Target* so that when you'll move the *Target* the *Hand* will also follow, which is very convenient.
- Give the *Lowerarm* an *IK* constraint, choose a *Length* of 2 so that it will move *Loweram* and *Upperarm* only, and choose the *Target* bone as the *Target* and the *Poletarget* bone as the *Pole Target*.
- If you want your *Hand* to stick to the *Lowerarm*, give it a *Copy Location* constraint with the *Lowerarm* as the *Target* and a *Head/Tail* value of 1.
- For the fingers: give the second phalanx a *Copy Rotation* constraint with the first phalanx as the *Target*, and give the third phalanx a *Copy Rotation* constraint with the second phalanx as the *Target* so that when you'll rotate the first phalanx the rest of the finger will follow.

[image]

A good thing would also be to choose a *B-Bone Display* for your armature (in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Display*), and to segment the *Upperarm* and *Lowerarm* so that they will bend smoothly (Go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Bendy Bones* > *Segments* and give 5 segments for example). In that case, give the *Lowerarm* an *Copy Rotation* constraint with the *Hand* as the *Target* and *Space* > *Pose Space* / *Pose Space*: when the Hand will rotate the *Lowerarm* and *Upperarm* will follow. Also, you could limit the rotation of these bones in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Inverse Kinematics*, but it's a bit tricky and most of the time you won't need it.

[image]

Comment: I didn't catch that last paragraph.. what do you mean by segments?

Comment: I've edited my answer: Go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Bendy Bones* > *Segments*

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of IK rigging an arm, from a simple one to lots of sofisticated mechanism.

One simple classic way is:
In edit mode:
- select the wrist bone and unparent it (Alt P, clear parent)
- select the first bone of a finger, shift select the first bone of all others 4 fingers, shift select (at last) the wirst bone, and parent them (Ctrl P, keep offset).
Select the Lower arm bone, go to bone constraints tab and add an IK constraint, setting the armature as target, the wirst bone as target bone and 2 as chain lenght.

[image]

In this way, moving the wirst bone will solidly moving all the fingers (as it's set as parent) and will IK moving Upper and lower arm by the Ik constraint.

If you set chain lenght to 3, also the shoulder bone will be affected by the IK constraint.

The only difference between the thumb and the others fingers is that a thumb has 2 phalanges, while the others 3, so generally we use 2 bones for the thumb and 3 bones for the others fingers.

Comment: Don't we have to set a pole target for the elbow like we do for the knee (saw a tutorial) and don't we have to set IK's throughout the fingers too?